# IndexError: list index out of range. python 3.3

Tags: python, python-3.3

```
userValue = 5
selection = []

if userValue == 1:
    selection.append("box")
if userValue == 2:
    selection.append("ball")
if userValue == 3:
    selection.append("pen")
if userValue == 4:
    selection.append("pencil")
elif():
    print ("please enter a correct value")

print (selection[0])
```

I am trying to store the value in a list and it keep giving me error and i have no idea how to do it, any help will be highly appreciated . thanks a lot in advance. :)

Comment: Your `elif` condition is empty, is it normal?

Comment: @MaximeLorant: looks like a botched `else:`; `()` is an empty tuple, so `elif():` is always false..

Answer (score 0):

The `userValue` is set to 5 at the beginning and the list is empty. So, you'll not pass in any `selection.append()` because 5 isn't equal to 1, to 2, to 3 or to 4.

You have the `print` statement of the `elif` condition and then you're trying to access to the first element of the empty list... which is impossible, so the exception is raised.
By the way, you should use the `else` keyword instead of `elif` with a *weird* condition.

A more Pythonic (and working) solution for your problem is:

```
userValue = 5
selection = []

# Create a tuple of string, in the same order as your if before
values = ("", "box", "ball", "pen", "pencil")

if userValue < len(values):
   selection.append(values[userValue])
   print (selection[0])
else:
   print ("please enter a correct value")
```

Answer (score 0):

You get an error because there isn't anything in your list. Each of your `if` tests are false, so nothing is added. Your `elif` block isn't executed either because your test, an empty tuple, evaluates to `false`. If you wanted a block that was executed if the previous blocks were false, an `else` would be a better choice.

If you want to prevent errors like this in the future, make sure you have an `else` block that adds something to the list after every series of `if`s that add things to an empty list based on user input.

Answer (score -1):

sectionvalue[0] is error because there is nothing in the list.
you must add anything to list

why there is error
    uservalue is 5
    in if block you didnt add condition to check value 5
    you use elif but it will never work its an empty tuple is evaluate to false

now selectionvalue is empty.but you tried to acess its 0 index its empty
if you try to access an empty lists index in python there will be an error.that you got

Comment: hey how my answer is -1

Comment: I minused it because your solution was incomplete at best.

Comment: @aovbros I assume it's because you didn't really explain why there's nothing in the list. Your answer is really vague. (I didn't downvote, just assumption)

Comment: is now better then please